# What could possibly cause a numeric overflow when enqueuing an Oracle AQ message?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

We create and enqueue messages with various properties, like this:

```sql
    message :=  sys.aq$_jms_message.construct(0);
                  message.set_string_property('a', v_a));
                  message.set_int_property('b', v_b);
                  message.set_int_property('c', v_c);
                  message.set_string_property('d', v_d);
    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(queue_name         => SOME_QUEUE,
                    enqueue_options    => queue_options,
                    message_properties => message_properties,
                    payload            => message,
                    msgid              => message_id);
```

After running this successfully for a long time, we are all of sudden getting

```
ORA-01426: numeric overflow ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_AQ"
```

What could possibly cause this?
Running the same enqueuing code against a newly created queue with new queue table produces the same result.

Comment: possibly you need to extend the width of one of your columns in the underlying queue table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this problem has nothing to do with message properties, and perhaps not even with the messages themselves. The cause here is actually a bug in Oracle, which you hit when the value of

```
select max(greatest(object_id, data_object_id)) from dba_objects;
```

reaches 2^31. There is actually a corresponding patch available from Oracle:

Patch 14837395: AQ CALLS FAIL WITH NUMERIC OVERFLOW WHEN DB OBJECT NUMBERS GREATER THAN 2^31